# How to get rid of black bars in embed youtube video

Tags: html, youtube

How I can get rid of black bars in youtube video? These black bars in top and in the bottom. Video is not mine, I can't edit video tags. I tried to use this string:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&volume=0&wmode=opaque&yt:crop=16:9"></iframe>
```

Everything works, but yt:crop=16:9 - not working.

Can you advise something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just to add a width and height?

```
<iframe width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&volume=0&wmode=opaque"></iframe>
```

Then the black bars on the sides disappears.

By the way I don't see any black bars at the top and the bottom, when running your code. Only on the sides.

Comment: Look here http://176.112.192.242:3174  Scroll the page, and you will see it. You see, this video can be changed via Admin panel and I need that another video will play with no black bars too. Even if this video will be crop a little, it's not matters.

Comment: Can't open it. Get a "This webpage is not available" error